# Display overlay icon on powershell in taskbar using forms

Tags: powershell, winforms

I've seem examples with xaml and powershell on adding an overlay icon to the taskbar of a running script: e.g. https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/01/adding-toolbar-icons-to-your-powershell-wpf-guis/

Is it possible to do this with a simple form?

Example form with "property doesnt exist" errors on what I think is the relevant property (TaskbarItemInfo)

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
$logo=[System.Drawing.Image]::Fromfile('C:\programdata\logo.png')
$icon=New-Object system.drawing.icon('C:\programdata\icon.ico')
$form=New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width=$logo.Width
$form.Height=$logo.Height
$form.TopMost=$true
$form.BackgroundImage=$logo
$form.AllowTransparency=$true
$form.TransparencyKey=$form.BackColor
$form.StartPosition=1
$form.FormBorderStyle=0
$form.Icon=$icon

$form.TaskbarItemInfo.Icon=$icon
$form.TaskbarItemInfo.Description=$form.Title

$form.showdialog()
```

Comment: Seems like `NotifyIcon` would do what you're looking for, tho it is independent from your form, can add a little example if you want

Comment: Please do, however I am referencing the taskbar icon, I know the example says tray(notification) but it shows in the taskbar overlaying the powershell icon.

Comment: The `TaskbarItemInfo` property you’re trying to use is not available in Windows Forms. It’s a property of the `Window` class in WPF.

Comment: @MartinIszac that is the answer... I ended up just making my form with WPF, ty